# Local gitorious http url

Tags: gitorious

I have setup a local gitorious server with hostname "localhost".
But it gives me an http URL like

http://git.localhost/abc/abc.git

So I cannot access via http.
In fact, I want to replace "localhost" with an IP address.
But the "git." part cause the problem.

How to solve the problem in order to access via http?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `/etc/hosts`:

```
git.<youhost>   <machine-ip>
```

This is a hack of gitorious to idenfify http/https requests. You can also use the self-diagnostic script to check for some errors.

```
$ sudo su git -c "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake diagnostics:summary"
```